# how to insert a property in typescript class which is not defined in the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, extends

i have a express app using typescript. there i am trying to use custom error handler for that i am trying to extend the error class.

**errorResponse.ts**

```
export default class ErrorResponse extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode, errorCode) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

typescript is giving error as the error interface which i extend has the following definition

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}
```

currently for workaround i have made it a javascript file. but how to use this as typescript file and use it correctly. so that the properties statusCode & errorCode does not give ts error.

version used "typescript": "^4.0.3"

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I see no point of extending an interface

Comment: @Saksham maybe it's the Error class only. I think when i went to definition of Error by (CTRL+click) in vscode, it took me to the error interface definition. so i misinterpreted the error class as error interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to extend [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) class and augment it with two new fields, the right way to do that is this:

[TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKkaZW)

```ts
export default class ErrorResponse extends Error {
  constructor(
    message: string,
    public statusCode: number,
    public errorCode: string
  ) {
    super(message);
  }
}

const e = new ErrorResponse("something", 404, "Not found");
e.errorCode; // works
e.message; // works
e.name; // works
```

Answer (score 0):

Class `Error` is an **interface**, and `ErrorResponse` is a **class**. So `ErrorResponse` can't extend `Error` but can implement it.

```
export default class ErrorResponse implements Error { // class 'implements' interface
    constructor(message, statusCode, errorCode) {
        this.message = message;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: but in implemented interfaces we can't use super. it gave error `'super' can only be referenced in a derived class` . maybe this is actually extending the error class

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. `super` would work if `Error` was also a class and not an interface, because interfaces don't have constructors i.e. can't be instantiated